# React Native Landscape to Portrait height bug

Tags: react-native, expo

I just created react native app with expo init, built for Android. When i open app in landscape mode and after turn to portrait, the height of app is half of screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzIlD.jpg

Here is code: https://github.com/catalin935/reactNativeHeightBug/blob/master/App.js

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. Do you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your view has been initialised with a height, perhaps `Dimensions.get('screen').height`?

If you want the view to always fill the screen, add `flex: 1` to the styles to get it to flex to it's container rather than using height/width values.

Alternatively, you could attach an event listener to Dimensions to listen for the `change` event and use that to rerender your views although I'd only really recommend that if you want your UI to change depending on the screen ratio/orientation (eg, set a FlatList to use two columns rather than one in landscape mode. I have a small library called [react-native-screenutils](https://github.com/JordanDuncan/react-native-screenutils/) that may help you with that.

Comment: Hi, Jordan! Thanks for reply. I already have flex: 1 on first <View>. Here is the code:
https://github.com/catalin935/reactNativeHeightBug/blob/master/App.js